# Insert php array into RDS

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, api, rds

So, I have a php script that writes to an RDS instance. However, the one variable that I am trying to insert is an array value so it is giving me some trouble. Here is my code. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

include 'mysql_connect.php';

// Select the database to use
mysql_select_db("database",$con);

// Describe the now-running instance to get the public URL
$result = $ec2Client->describeInstances(array(
    'InstanceIds' => $instanceIds,
));


$server_record = mysql_query("INSERT INTO server_tbl (userName, serverName, serverId, isRunning) VALUES ('$name', 'runtest', '$instanceIds', 'X'");

print_r($instanceIds);

?>
```

Comment: $instanceIds is an array an you want to insert it ?

Answer (score 0):

there are many methods, but all depend on your choice.

1.

```
$instanceIdsstr = serialize($instanceIds);//to save in db
$instanceIds    = unserialize($instanceIdsstr);//to extract
```

2.

```
$instanceIdsstr =json_encode($instanceIds);//to save in db
$instanceIds    =  json_decode($instanceIdsstr);//to extract
```

3.

```
$instanceIdsstr = implode("|MYDELI|",$instanceIds);//to save in db
$instanceIds    = explode("|MYDELI|",$instanceIdsstr);//to extract
```

Another option You can save as XML.

Example:

```
$test=array('username'=>$username,'field2'=>'value2');
$instanceIdsstr =json_encode($test);//this will keep all info in string
```

Comment: MADTerry, thank you for your answer. My problem is that I define the username and other values and need them to insert with the InstanceIds. Do you know how to do that.